# Visual Studio Code Error while running the basic stateless widget app.( Most probably a problem with some installation files)

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am new to app dev, I am facing an error as I use flutter in vscode to use it for a test drive. So far I have followed: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive.
I have run flutter doctor multiple times to make sure there's nothing left to install.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
PS E:\vscodeproj\flutter_application_2> dart "e:\vscodeproj\flutter_application_2\lib\main.dart"
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui' 
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
```

I wanted to test drive the application on my physical device. The app ended up giving error in gradle as well as 'dart.ui' error in vscode.

Comment: Why does the drive letter D: have a '/' before it?

Comment: @GrahamD I'm not too sure about that. This is something I've copied off of the error that I got in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to run your Flutter app using the command line `dart "e:\vscodeproj\flutter_application_2\lib\main.dart"`. This is not the way to do it.

Basically, in VSCode you need to connect to a device (emulator or physical via usb) and then use an option from the 'Run' menu or the green arrow.

If you had a device connected then you could simply type `flutter run` at the command line.

There is much information on the web on how to start with Flutter. You really need to work through one such as this: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code